Some Material Icons not working with Angular Material
I am trying to use the keep Material icon but it's not working.
When I use the following HTML, i am able to see the first two icons, but not the keep one. I've noticed this issue with other icons, too. Any idea what the issue could be?
<mat-icon
  aria-hidden="false"
  aria-label="Example home icon"
  fontIcon="home"
></mat-icon>
<mat-icon
  aria-hidden="false"
  aria-label="Example home icon"
  fontIcon="grading"
></mat-icon> 
<mat-icon
  aria-hidden="false"
  aria-label="Example home icon"
  fontIcon="keep"
></mat-icon>


Link to stackblitz showing the problem

The "keep" icon is from the Material Symbols Outlined font family. Surprisingly the "grading" icon is also from the same font family.
Cannot reproduce why the "grading" icon can be worked without importing the stylesheet and specifying the fontSet attribute.
For the "keep" icon solution,

Import the stylesheet in the index.html file.

<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined"
/>


Specify the fontSet attribute and providing the "keep" word as below:

<mat-icon
  aria-hidden="false"
  aria-label="Example home icon"
  fontSet="material-symbols-outlined"
>
  keep
</mat-icon>

Demo @ StackBlitz
Reference: Mat Icon

You can specify an alternate font by setting the fontSet input to either the CSS class to apply to use the desired font, or to an alias previously registered with MatIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias. Examples:

<mat-icon fontSet="myfont">sun</mat-icon>

